# Mark text in html (JS/Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How to highlight text in html? I have a ready html article and I want to mark the text there.

I'm trying:

```
search= ""

 let words = el.text.split(' ')
        for (let key in words) {
          if (words[key].includes(this.search)) {
            words[key] = "<mark>" + words[key] + "</mark>";
          }
        }
        el.text = n.join(" ");
```

highlighting plain text works well:

*The website was created by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky in 2008.*

but what about complex markup and html tags:

```
<p><b>Stack Overflow</b> is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is a privately held website, the flagship site of the <a href="/wiki/Stack_Exchange" title="Stack Exchange">Stack Exchange Network</a>
```

How to split into array elements:
text: `<h1>Stack Overflow<h1> is a question and <p>answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.</p>`
If we search **"Stack"** - will be mark `<mark><h1>Stack</mark>`